# Как вывести значение ключа в словаре python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть json файл, я пишу функцию используя, которую можно вывести значения всех ключей сразу или по отдельности.

```py
import json

def get_keys_value(some_argumnet):
with open('filename.json') as f:
    data = json.load(open("schedule.json", 'rb'))
    if some_argument == 'Print 1st key value':
        print(data[0])
    elif some_argument == 'Print 2nd kay value':
         print(data[1])
```

Я не знаю как выводить значение ключей. Через индекс не получилось.

Comment: Значение ключей нужно выводить через ключи... В этом и есть основная идея словаря, зачем же Вам индексы?

Comment: Думал что через индекс тоже можно. Теперь буду юзать значения. Спасибо!

Comment: @mash_ элементы словаря не упорядочены, поэтому индекса у них нет